# Having trouble getting my page to work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Ok im going to copy pasta my HTML and JS in a moment. but a quick rundown first so you understand where im coming from.

Im in Javascript 101 essentially, and we're about six weeks in. I have a project going on where i need to do all of the following.

**Requirements**

1.Design and structure (10 points)
Use external CSS and JS files.
Make sure you have a header, footer, styled text, colors, etc.
Be creative.

2.Forms (10 points)
Your project must use forms. Make sure to use the appropriate field types and make sure they are accessible.

3.jQuery (10 points)
Unobtrusive jQuery must be used. At a bare minimum, use it in place of events (.onload, .onclick, .onsubmit, etc.) and .getElementById().

4.Tabs (10 points)
Your site must use at least three tabs: (1) your lesson, (2) your form, (3) conclusion /wrap up. You may use the code from the example in class, but make sure it is documented and the styles are completely different than the example.

5.Documentation
(10 points)
Make sure all of your code is well documented.

So now you know what i am trying to accomplish. Problem is the everything we were taught for jQuery was from either Codecademy, or in class. The book we use (Modern Javascript - Develop and Design by Larry Ullman) has nothing about jQuery. As you can see in the requirements, i cant use "getelementid" and such, which i  do understand how to use.

So at this point, i dont know if im completely lost, or if it's merely syntax issues, im literally that lost. What i do have is more or less my understanding of Jquery, mixed in with some code copied from a few examples.

**Here's my Html-**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Health Calculator</title>
<link id="theme" href="vader/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Health Calculator</h2>

<!-- tabs setup for page -->
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">First</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Second</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Third</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
    <p><strong>Exercise</strong></p>
    <!-- Form for page one -->
    <form>
<p><strong>Activity factor</strong></p>
<!-- Setup Radio buttons -->
<p>
    <input type="radio" name="activity" id="sed">
    <label for="sed" id="sedLabel">Sedentary = BMR X 1.2 (little or no exercise, desk job)</label>
</p>
<p>
    <input type="radio" name="activity" id="lit">
    <label for="lit" id="litLabel">Lightly active = BMR X 1.375 (light exercise/sports 1-3 days/wk)</label>
</p>
<p>
    <input type="radio" name="activity" id="mod">
    <label for="mod" id="modLabel">Mod. active = BMR X 1.55 (moderate exercise/sports 3-5 days/wk)</label>
</p>
<p>
    <input type="radio" name="activity" id="very">
    <label for="very" id="veryLabel">Very active = BMR X 1.725 (hard exercise/sports 6-7 days/wk)</label>
</p>
<p>
    <input type="radio" name="activity" id="ext">
    <label for="ext" id="extLabel">Extr. Active = BMR X 1.9 (hard daily exercise/sports &amp; physical job   or 2 X day training, marathon, football camp, contest, etc.)</label>
</p>

</form>

 </p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
    <!-- tab 2 -->
    <p>Diet - Caloric maintenance</p>
    <!-- The equation is currently shown for reference -->
    <p>Men: BMR = 66 + (13.7 X wt in kg) + (5 X ht in cm) - (6.8 X age in years)</p>
    // Form for weight, height, and age of Caloric Maintenance calc.
    <!-- Form to all text entry for values -->
   <form>

    <label for="txtWeight">Weight:</label>
    <input type="text" class="txtInput" id="txtWeight" value="0">
    <label for="txtHeight">Height:</label>
    <input type="text" class="txtInput" id="txtHeight" value="0">
    <label for="txtAge">Age:</label>
    <input type="text" class="txtInput" id="txtAge" value="0">
    <br>
     <input type="button" id="btnCalc1" value="Calculate"> <p id="result">Result</p>

</form>
    <p>------------------------------------------</p>

    <br>
   <form>

    <label for="txtWeight">Lbs to Kg::</label>
    <input type="text" class="txtInput" id="txtLbs" value="0">
    <br>
    <input type="button" id="btnCalc2" value="Calculate"> <p id="result2">Result</p>
    <label for="txtHeight">Inches to Cm:</label>
    <input type="text" class="txtInput" id="txtInch" value="0">

    <br>
     <input type="button" id="btnCalc3" value="Calculate"> <p id="result3">Result</p>
</form>
</div>

    <div id="tabs-3">
    <!-- tab 3 -->
    <p>BMI Calculator</p>
    <!-- The equation is currently shown for reference -->
    <p>BMI = (Mass (lb)/height(in)^2) * 703</p>
    <!-- Form to all text entry for values -->
    <form>

    <label for="txtMass">Mass in Lbs:</label>
    <input type="text" class="txtInput" id="txtMass" value="0">
    <label for="txtHinch">Height in Inches:</label>
    <input type="text" class="txtInput" id="txtInput" value="0">
    <br>
    <input type="button" id="btnCalc4" value="Calculate"> <p id="result4">Result</p>

 </form>
 </div>
<!-- This whole section below blows my damn mind -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="Class11Example.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**And here is my Javascript:**

```
$(function(){
    $('#tabs').tabs();

    // attach event listener to button click
    $('.themeButton').click(function(){
        // This was stuff i got from a class example, i tried erasing it but without it my page doesnt work. I no longer have the button so i don understand why i need it.
        $('#theme').attr("href", this.id + "/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css");
    });
});

// Tab 2
$(function(){
    //Identify Variables
    var txtWeight, txtHeight, txtAge;
    // attach event listener to the toggle button's click event
    $('#btnCalc1').click(function(){
        result = 66 + (13.7 * $('#txtWeight').val())  + (5 * $('#txtHeight').val()) - (6.8 * $('#txtAge').val()).html();
    });

});

// Still Tab 2, but second half
$(function(){
    //Identify Variables
    var txtInch, txtLbs;
    // attach event listener to the toggle button's click event
    $('#btnCalc3').click(function(){
    result3 = $('#txtInch').val() * 2.54.html();
    });
    $('#btnCal2').click(function() {
    result2 = $('#txtLbs').val() * 0.45359237.html();
    });

});

//Tab 3 
$(function(){
    //Identify Variables
    var txtMass, txtHinch;
    // attach event listener to the toggle button's click event
    $('#btnCalc3').click(function(){
    result4 = $('#txtMass').val() / (($('#txtHinch')^2) * 703).html();
    });


});
```

Im also aware that i need a few other things, footer, some more CSS, etc. but thats easy imo, im trying to get the  hard stuff done first, then i can finish the "basic" stuff. Also this refers to some files i downloaded from JqueryUI.com, and its massive minified content, i assume you dont need that since it's a massive wall of text.

On to the problem. None of my buttons actually calculate anything. I dont know if they're not linked correctly, or my equations dont make sense, if its syntax, etc. Being so clueless on the matter and not really knowing where to find the answers is making this quite frusturating.

Finally, im not looking for somebody to outright do my homework for me. I do want to understand this, why things aren't working, and what i did wrong. I going to school to be a web designer, so i need to understand this going forward.

Thank you ahead of time.

(edit: some formatting issues)

Edit two!

Here is my updated code using JSfiddle, as well as a few questions to finish this up.

I have a few other questions specifically im hoping i can get help with. Here is first off, the updated JSfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/vtexekn4/

I need help with a couple other minor things.

First, the radio selections in tab 1 are supposed to modify the end calorie maintenance daily in tab 2's result, how can i bring that in to the equation? (Im assuming it would have to do with the input type? How would i code that)
How can i have it so that it's not an alert, and that i replace the word "result" below the buttons, with the actual result. So a swap of text, also so that the text will stay there (since an alert is essentially a window on top, and therefor doesnt allow you to see the text after u "ok" it, and the conversion calculators are there so that you can see what your numbers are post. I think it would be problematic to have to keep going back to alerts if you forgot the numbers)

Comment: Since you're in 101 I don't know if you've discovered this yet but JSFiddle is an excellent tool for posting your broken examples so that others can see what's broken and 'fiddle' with it to fix it. It's far easier to see what it is/isn't doing than visually imagine your code =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you have confused the `.html()` jquery method. For example you have something like:

```
result = (10 * $('#...').val()).html();
```

The problem is that result is now a number (since we multipled 10 * some value). A number does not have a `.html()` extension method so it is throwing an error.

I've removed the `.html()` on the Caloric Maintenance Calc section and added an alert to show you what result equals. This should give you a good starting point. Fill in your Weight, Height and Age and click Calculate then it will show an alert dialog with the `result`.

Here's the [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4shkfegq/5/)

You might also wish to look into using something like Chrome's developer tools, Firefox's Firebug etc. for debugging your Javascript.

Comment: Ok, first off, ty for the advice on JSfiddle, i am using it now in the edit above. Secondly, the removal of .html fixed it the equation, and it's good to know i had majority of the code right. I have a few other questions specifically im hoping you or anybody else can help with. I put them at the end of the edited main topic. Thank you very much sir, you are an absolute life saver.

Comment: @KyleSchmelzer Glad it helped. TBH you'd be better off starting a new question for the new questions =) ...the alert was just an example to show you the result was in fact working. Take a look at the example for .html(string) here -> http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2

Comment: @KyleSchmelzer http://jsfiddle.net/vtexekn4/6/ -I removed the tabs 'cause it wasn't working. But it illustrates what you want to do anyway.